# Output arraylist of objects (I/O)

Tags: java, file-io, arraylist

I have an arraylist filled with objects (Lines, rectangles, ovals). I need to somehow export the list and save it into a txt,csv, etc... file and be able to load it into the list again. How how i go into doing that. I looked all over the internet but i couldn't find out how to export arraylist objects and re import them

Comment: You probably want to look into the `Serializable` interface and `Java IO`

Comment: Should the output file be readable by another program or only by your program (or another Java program that has access to your class)? In the first case, you'll have to decide the format and then write conversion methods from and to text. In the second case, look up Java serialization (how to write Java objects as bytes). The second case is a lot easier, of course.

Comment: It only needs to be readable by the java program but it can be readable by anything.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** this solution saves the data in a binary format that is not human readable.

You need to serialize your data in a stream of bytes. 
You can use `ObjectOutputStream` that is a standard java class or built your custom system to serialize deserialize data and save them to a file.

Here is an example of code directly from [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html)

```
// Write file
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("t.tmp");
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

oos.writeInt(12345);
oos.writeObject("Today");
oos.writeObject(new Date());
oos.close();
```

Comment: He said txt, csv, not binary

Comment: I edited the answer, thank you Mackiavelli for your correction

Comment: Actually, OP writes "**save it into a txt,csv, etc...**", so any format should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

How about JSON?

It is human-readable for debugging purposes etc, can be easily read by other programs and interfaces and is a widely used way to transfer objects.

A nice implementation for Java is [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson). Its pretty fast and very well documented.